# How do I read a file with characters, and place them into an 2D int array?

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I'm attempting to code the game of life by reading files, each with their own blinkers written as asterisks, which I then read, and only assign into an array element if there are asterisks.

**For example:**

```
int [] [] grid = new int [x][y];    
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        int count;
        int charCount;
        int x;
        int y;

        for (count =0 ; file.hasNext();count++ )                    
        {
            file.nextLine();            
            x = count;                                                  
            for(charCount = 0; file.hasNext(); charCount++);                        
                file.findInLine("*").charAt(charCount);
                y = charCount;
```

**In pseudo code:**

```
for each row in rows
  read row from file
for each character in row
    check if character is an asterisk
        set value of integer array at row, col
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to ask a more specific question than this. Are you asking how to assign a char to an int array? Or how to refer to an index in an array? As it stands the question reads as though you are asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: to ensure everyone will understand what you are asking, include (IN THE QUESTION) sample from the file you are reading, and what is the problem you are facing with your code, don't expect everyone will know what **game of life** is!

Comment: @sprinter I'm trying to read a character of a string into a 2D int array. The code above is what I have so far, which is my attempt to calculate the total rows assigned to the variable count, and total columns assigned to the variable charCount, which I then feed into an array to eventually print it. The code returns errors, so I'm interested in knowing where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Khan there are quite a few issues in the code you've posted. For example, there is a semicolon at the end of the inner for statement which means it won't do anything (it's executing an empty statement in each iteration). There are several steps in 'read a character of a string into a 2D int array'. You will need to explain exactly where you are having an issue.